# Cannot install therubyracer -v 0.9.9, out of solutions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, therubyracer

I'm trying to install Dradis on my Mac, and it has to include therubyracer(version: 0.9.9) in the installation, I tried all the suggestions in other posts but none of them worked. I'm wondering if there is any way to install it? Thank you!!!

#### Updated question:

I uninstalled libv8 and reinstalled it, it seems to be working fine. Then I reran 
" gem install therubyracer -v '0.9.9', and here is a new and fresh error message: Does this new message ring any bell? Thank you all!

Successfully installed libv8-3.3.10.4
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/Users/Prime/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:

```
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/Prime/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby
--with-objclib
--without-objclib
```

extconf.rb:15:in `<main>': undefined method`include_path' for Libv8:Module (NoMethodError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Prime/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/therubyracer-0.9.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Prime/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/1.9.1/therubyracer-0.9.9/gem_make.out

Comment: Did you recently update XCode?

Comment: Yes, I updated to -v 6 about two weeks ago, is that the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this problem has to do with a recent update of XCode. After a XCode update you need to do the following steps:

1. Open Xcode and accept the license agreement
2. Reinstall the Command Line Tools.

The second step seems to depend on your OS versions. One of the following steps should work:

- Open your console and run `xcode-select --install`, or
- Start the `Install Command Line Developer Tools` app in `/System/Library/CoreServices`.

After reinstalling the Command Line Tools try to rerun `bundle install`.

Comment: Thank you sir! I tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I ran "bundle install" in Dradis/server, and it ended with an error like this: Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. .... AND "An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.9.9), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.9.9'` succeeds before bundling." Then I tried to install rubyracer as instructed, and the same error(as my question) occurred.